# AWS Application load balancer in switching between two frontends

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, load-balancing, amazon-alb, angular

I have two angular6 frontends, one running on port 4000, the second running on 4100.

Do a Dockerized push to ECR and create two task definitions ... create cluster and then 2 services of these two frontends, both are running on their ports well and good.

Now I create an application load balancer with ssl, default traffic to port 4000 frontend on domain driver.com. Then add a rule for the second frontend, like:

```
Host driver.com
Path /secondfrontend
```

so it becomes `driver.com/secondfrontend`

I get the secondfrontend but it's blank

Comment: Have you been able to reference the second port number anywhere?

Comment: Yess .. 
I have two target groups on each target i have my two frontend services .. one has port 4000 that target is default access target with driver.com and other is on 4100 and i add that target group in rules

Comment: i have specify host and path and than forward to the second frontend target group

Comment: When you say "blank". What exactly do you mean? Are both ports 4000 and 4100 open in your Security Group?

Comment: yeah through ip it is working fine .. both load well

Answer (score -2):

It was path base routing problem 
removing path base routing and left only host based works fine